# LockFree Queue with Gcc builtins

Tags: c, gcc, queue, atomic, lock-free

I am working on developing a single write/reader lock_free queue that is placed on a shared memory which is going to be opened by two different Linux processes. Both processes open the shm with MAP_SHARED.

The queue looks like this:

```
typedef stuct {
    unsigned char Data[ 256 ];
} Element_Type;
typedef struct {
    unsigned int Snd_Cnt;
    unsigned int Rcv_Cnt;
    Element_Type Elems[ 100 ];
} Queue_Type;
```

OBS: Both Linux processes open the same shared memory and view it as a pointer to the Queue_Type. Let us say that the pointer is Shm_p.

The Linux process which is the writer does like this:

```
Tmp_Snd_Cnt = (Shm_p->Snd_Cnt + 1u) % 100;
__atomic_load(&Shm_p>Rcv_Cnt, &Tmp_Rcv_Cnt, __ATOMIC_ACQUIRE);
if (Tmp_Snd_Cnt != Tmp_Rcv_Cnt) {
    memcpy(&Shm_p->Elems[ Tmp_Snd_Cnt ].Data[ 0 ], pointer_to_real_data, size_of_real_data <= 256);
    __atomic_store(&Shm_p>Snd_Cnt, &Tmp_Snd_Cnt, __ATOMIC_RELEASE);
}
```

The Linux process which is the reader does like this:

```
Tmp_Rcv_Cnt = Shm_p->Rcv_Cnt;
__atomic_load(&Shm_p>Snd_Cnt, &Tmp_Snd_Cnt, __ATOMIC_ACQUIRE);
if (Tmp_Snd_Cnt != Tmp_Rcv_Cnt) {
    pointer_to_real_data = &Shm_p->Elems[ Tmp_Rcv_Cnt ].Data[ 0 ];
    Tmp_Rcv_Cnt = (Tmp_Rcv_Cnt + 1u) % 100;
    __atomic_store(&Shm_p>Rcv_Cnt, &Tmp_Rcv_Cnt, __ATOMIC_RELEASE);
}
```

My question is do you see any problems with such an approach like races & stuff?

That what I have seen is the following:
Sometimes the reader gets pointer_to_real_data to point to un-updated data. This suggests that GCC has placed the memcpy after the atomic_store (i.e. compile-time instruction reordering). To mitigate this, I have placed `asm volatile("" : : : "memory")` right before the atomic store in the writer code. The reader got correct data.

To make things even stranger I took away the asm volatile and compiled again.
The code started to work. (I have cleared the shm before testing again).

So obviously the compiler did something strange in the first case without the asm volatile when the reader got un-updated data. What could have been?

Now, in order to be safe, I have the asm volatile there in order to instruct the compiler to not reorder the code.

Thanks in advance.

LATER EDIT (in order to mitigate the problem with over-writing the pointer_to_real_data in the case when the reader gets slow after the store of Rcv_Cnt):

```
typedef stuct {
    unsigned char Data[ 256u ];
} Base_Element_Type;
typedef stuct {
    unsigned int      Idx;
    Base_Element_Type Base_Elems[ 2u ];
} Element_Type;
typedef struct {
    unsigned int Snd_Cnt;
    unsigned int Rcv_Cnt;
    Element_Type Elems[ 100u ];
} Queue_Type;
```

Writer code:

```
Tmp_Snd_Cnt = (Shm_p->Snd_Cnt + 1u) % 100u;
__atomic_load(&Shm_p>Rcv_Cnt, &Tmp_Rcv_Cnt, __ATOMIC_ACQUIRE);
if (Tmp_Snd_Cnt != Tmp_Rcv_Cnt) {
    Elem_p = &Shm_p->Elems[ Tmp_Snd_Cnt ];
    memcpy(&Elem_p->Base_Elems[ Elem_p->Idx ].Data[ 0u ], pointer_to_real_data, size_of_real_data <= 256u);
    __atomic_store(&Shm_p>Snd_Cnt, &Tmp_Snd_Cnt, __ATOMIC_RELEASE);
}
```

Reader code:

```
Tmp_Rcv_Cnt = Shm_p->Rcv_Cnt;
__atomic_load(&Shm_p>Snd_Cnt, &Tmp_Snd_Cnt, __ATOMIC_ACQUIRE);
if (Tmp_Snd_Cnt != Tmp_Rcv_Cnt) {
    Elem_p = &Shm_p->Elems[ Tmp_Rcv_Cnt ];
    pointer_to_real_data = &Elem_p->Base_Elems[ Elem_p->Idx ].Data[ 0u ];
    Elem_p->Idx = (Elem_p->Idx + 1u) % 2u;  
    Tmp_Rcv_Cnt = (Tmp_Rcv_Cnt + 1u) % 100u;
    __atomic_store(&Shm_p>Rcv_Cnt, &Tmp_Rcv_Cnt, __ATOMIC_RELEASE);
}
```

This should work ... right?!

Comment: Usually you'd use a power-of-2 size to make the modulo operation even cheaper.  At least your size is a compile-time constant so it can use a multiplicative inverse.  And BTW, your code would be more readable if you used `Tmp_Rcv_Cnt = __atomic_load_n(&Shm_p>Snd_Cnt, __ATOMIC_ACQUIRE)`, instead of the `void` version that takes a destination pointer.

Comment: I'm not confident your lockfree logic works.  The compiler shouldn't be able to reorder the `memcpy` to after a release-store, but you could have checked that by looking at the asm (or posting it here), if you still have the executable that didn't seem to work.  I assume you compiled with optimization enabled?  Otherwise everything is effectively `volatile` anyway.

Comment: The reader doesn't copy the data out of the queue before marking the entry as read, so you have possible re-use of the slot, don't you?  If the reader blocks and the writer wraps all the way around and overwrites the data between `pointer_to_real_data = ...` and actually dereferencing that pointer.

Comment: @PeterCordes what do you mean with my lock free logic doesn’t work?

Comment: @PeterCordes agree! Shall fix that! Thanks!